# Notepad++, Insert text from one list into another?

Tags: notepad++

I have 2 lists on separate pages in notepad++, I'd like to add the text from one list to the start of each line on the 2nd list, eg:

```
LIST 1
1abc
2abc
3abc

LIST 2
=test
=test
=test

RESULT
1abc=test
2abc=test
3abc=test
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the text in your second list the same all the way down, or does it vary by line?

Answer (score 1):

in notepad++ you can press alt+right click and select column. then you can copy and paste it where every you want.

Or open both files in excel and you will be able to do column manipulation as well.

Comment: in notepad++ you can use macros as well to perform this task